# Center bar between grid lines | MPChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using Android MPChart library to show some graphs in my application. I have to create a bar graph, and the customer would like to have the bars between the grid lines, like the ios app:

[image]

Right now what I managed to do is

[image]

But I can't find a way to center the bar betweem the grid lines.

Is that possible somehow ?

Comment: The grid lines and the content (e.g. bars) on the chart are generally fairly disconnected in MPAndroidChart. Have you tried just removing the gridlines and drawing your own lines where you want them?